# Using n- sift code

Tags: cygwin, sift, itk

I want to use N-SIFT (n-dimensional scale invariant feature transform)feature points to detect some spatio-temporal scale invariant regions in a video. I have got the code from the following link
http://www.insight-journal.org/browse/publication/207

It builds the tool on Cygwin platform and uses ITK. No detailed description is given on how to build it. So if any one using this tool/library please help me to build it. Or please mention any other library for the same if available.

Answer (score 0):

To build the project I needed to add following line to CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0) # <- give version you have
```

and change all lines:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( ... ITKCommon ITKIO)
```

into

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( .... ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

..and use CMake to build it, e.g.:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
```

If you only process 2-D video, you can also use ASIFT library you can find it here: http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2011/my-asift/

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am trying to build it on 64 bit windows 7. I have made the changes and configured using gui based cmake (version 3.0.1). It worked without error but how to connect with ITK tool? And how to call the library?do I need to call from the cygwin command window?  Will configuring and generating using gui based cmake does the work?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly "connect with ITK tool" means. You can find examples how to use n-sift filter with other ITK filters in "testnD.cxx" program in the project main directory. After build the project on Archlinux platform I successfuly run "make test" which calls "testnD.cxx".

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer of ralv worked, but I also had to manually set the `ITK-DIR` variable in the `cmake` configurations (I used `ccmake` to do the configurations, instead of cmake) to the directory where the file ITKConfig.cmake was located.